# In Mac OS X, what is the difference between "Standard" and "English" order for sorted lists?

Tags: macos, language

In the Language & Text preference pane (or International for versions older than Snow Leopard) what is the difference between "Standard" and "English" order for sorted lists?

I found this [article](http://docs.info.apple.com/jarticle.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/8233.html) that clearly explains the difference between "Standard" and "English (United States, Computer)" for word breaks, but it is not clear about sorted lists.

Answer (score 6):

It;s possible that 'standard' means it will sort according to 'the unicode standard' - see this page for a short description of [how finder sorts](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22935?viewlocale=en_US) it's output.  From the page referenced:

> **The Unicode standard**
>
> Technically speaking, Finder sorting is based on the Unicode Collation Algorithm, defined by the Unicode Consortium. This standard provides a complete and unambiguous sort ordering for all Unicode characters, and is available on the Unicode Consortium website. Other operating systems or applications may use different rules that can make the same list of items sort in a different way.

There are different ways to sort alpabets - english is one order, but there are not only other language specific orderings, but 'generic' sort orders and many others.  'Standard' may refer to the ISO14651 standard sort order.  If you really want to dive in, read [this](http://www.cs.uvm.edu/oracle9doc/server.901/a90236/ch4.htm).